# Nop Commerce 3.4 Address validation fails if the country has no state

Tags: c#, .net, nopcommerce

I am currently working in a project which uses NopCommerce 3.40. But I am facing a problem validating address where country has no state. For example -

[image]

What I require is -

1. For countries with states like US , AU state should be required.
2. For all other countries state should be optional.

Is it currently possible in NopCommerce? or am I missing something? Is it possible without tweaking the code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do without touching the code. But it would need considerable time to fix.

In admin,

1. Go to Configuration ==> Countries
2. then click edit.
3. Now Select "State and Province" Tab.
4. Add a state with a name similar to  "N/A" or "" With blank.
5. Do step 1 to 4 for all the countries except US, AUS or where applicable.

If you can update code, it can be done easily. Other hand if you don't want to use state at all, then it can be disabled from admin too.

Comment: But that will also be shown while showing address, right?

Comment: Yes. That's the best we can do as per your requirement.